# NullPointerException Error in Method .But Method field is fetching value

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception, file-handling

```
Class A
{
    Class B
    {
        ArrayList<MultiGridImageNode>   a
        Bitmap                          b
        ByteBuffer                      c
    }

    B bb;

    save()
    {
        //Load will use Save method to fetch all stored value in file(which is correct)
    }

    load(B cc)
    {
        //this P.x and P.y . I am fetching from file one by one (while debugging i can see correct value)
        Point P;
        cc.a.get(i).add(P)   //Still NULL POINTER EXCEPTION ERROR 
    }
}
```

Comment: I DONT KNOW WHY I AM GETTING NULL POINTER EXCPTION IN LOAD BUT WHILE DEBUGGING I CAN SEE THAT I AM GETTING CORRECT VALUE FROM FILE BUT STILL cc.a.get(i).add(p) giving me null pointer exception error

Comment: I assume that you're using Java? If so, please use the 'java' tag.

Answer (score 0):

None of your objects has been initialized. Simply declaring them does not instantiate new objects. Try something like this:

```
Class A
{
    Class B
    {
        ArrayList<MultiGridImageNode>   a = new ArrayList<MultiGridImageNode>(); // <----
        Bitmap                          b = new Bitmap(); // <----
        ByteBuffer                      c = new ByteBuffer(); // <----
    }

    B bb = new B(); // <----

    save()
    {
        //Load will use Save method to fetch all stored value in file(which is correct)
    }

    load(B cc)
    {
        //this P.x and P.y . I am fetching from file one by one (while debugging i can see correct value)
        Point P = new Point(); // <----
        cc.a.get(i).add(P)   //Still NULL POINTER EXCEPTION ERROR 
    }
}
```

I marked changes with `// <----`.